# jdbc procedure for callling and saving the data into my sql table

Tags: spring, templates, jdbc

This is my dbprocess **impl.java**

```
@Override
        public HashMap executeProcedure (String packName,String spname, HashMap inParamMap)
        {
            System.out.println("inParamMap "+inParamMap+" spname "+spname);
            Map simpleJdbcCallResult=null;
            try{
                //jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
                SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);   
                // simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName(procedureName)
                simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withCatalogName(packName)
                .withProcedureName(spname);
                SqlParameterSource inputPara = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);
                System.out.println("SqlParameterSource:::"+inputPara.toString());
                simpleJdbcCallResult = simpleJdbcCall.execute(inputPara);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                try {
                    jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
```

This is my **ORGMASTERDAO.java**

```
HashMap<String, Object> outParam = dbProcess.executeProcedure("", "Pr_Org_Master", inputParamList);

        System.out.println("outParam "+outParam);
        Set outResult = outParam.entrySet();
        System.out.println("outparam SIZE "+outParam.size());
```

I am getting the following error after compiling the program please suggest me for the same:

> Parameter index out of range (27 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:

Comment: please arrange your content and we need some more explanations about it.

Comment: Looks like you passed 27 input parameters to be bound, but your SQL statement has no bind parameters (e.g. SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE X = ?).

Comment: when i am using mysql connector  this code is working fine but when i am using stored procedure the above error is appearing. Any suggestion

Comment: @kumarseen sir what content u need